# How do I trigger a jquery action when someone clicks submit

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, widgetkit

This isn't specific to Joomla except that I'm triggering a yootheme Widgetkit action. I have an email sign up form that loads via a javascript, and I've placed it inside a widgetkit lightbox.

I've seen this page:
http://yootheme.com/support/question/36003
And it shows the command needed:
('#lightbox-close').trigger('click')
running this would trigger the close action on the modal lightbox, closing it.

But because the submit button on this form is pulled into the page via javascript, I can't edit the form itself.

So I was trying to put the script above the form.

Here's what I know for sure doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("#e2ma_signup_submit_button").click(function () {
$('#lightbox-close').trigger('click');
});</script>
```

e2ma_signup_submit_button is the ID of the submit button in the form.

Anyone with any amount of jquery skill can probably get this working in a few seconds, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#e2ma_signup_submit_button').on('click', function() {
        $('#lightbox-close').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

If it doesn't work, replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

[JSFiddle - Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zb1f8guL/)

Comment: Yes! I had to use the JQuery line, but it totally works. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.